# UnauthorizedAccessException on newly created files

Tags: c#, file-access

I have an application that is looking through some files for old data. In order to make sure we don't corrupt good projects, I'm copying the files to a temporary location. Some of the directories I'm checking are source-code directories, and they have .svn folders. We use Subversion to manage our code.

Once I've searched through all of the files, I want to delete the temp cache. Sounds easy, right?

For some reason, all of my .svn directories won't delete from the cache. They crash the app.

For reasons (too deep to go into here), I have to use the temp folder, so just "scan the original file" is out of the question for political reasons.

I can go into explorer and delete them. No problem. No warnings. Just deletes. But the code crashes with "Access to {file} is denied." I'm at my wits end with this one, so any help would be appreciated.

While I've simplified the function a LITTLE for sake of your sanity, the code REALLY is about this simple.

```
List<string> tmpCacheManifest = new List<string>();
string oldRootPath = "C:\\some\\known\\directory\\";
string tempPath = "C:\\temp\\cache\\";

foreach (string file in ListOfFilesToScan)
{
    string newFile = file.Replace(oldRootPath, tempPath);

    // This works just fine.
    File.Copy(file, newFile);

    tmpCacheManifest.add(newFile);
}

//    ... do some stuff to the cache to verify what I need.


// Okay.. I'm done.. Delete the cache.
foreach (string file in tmpCacheManifest)
{
   // CRASH!
   File.Delete(file);
}
```

*** Update ***: The exception is UnauthorizedAccessException. The text is "Access to the path 'C:\temp\cache\some-sub-dirs\.svn\entries' is denied."

It happens under XP, XP-Pro and Windows 7.

*** Update 2 *** None of my validation even ATTEMPTS to look at subversion files. I do need them, however. That's part of the political crap. I have to show that EVERY file was copied... wheter it was scanned or not.

And I realize what the usual suspects are for File.Delete. I realize what UnauthorizedAccessException means. I don't have access. That's a no-brainer. But I just copied the file. How can I *NOT* have access to the file?

*** Update 3 ***
The answer was in the "read-only" flag. Here's the code I used to fix it:

```
    foreach (string file in ListOfFilesToScan)
{
    string newFile = file.Replace(oldRootPath, tempPath);

    // This works just fine.
    File.Copy(file, newFile);

    //// NEW CODE ////
    // Clear any "Read-Only" flags
    FileInfo fi3 = new FileInfo(fn);
    if ((fi3.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
    {
        fi3.Attributes = (FileAttributes)(Convert.ToInt32(fi3.Attributes) - Convert.ToInt32(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
    }



    tmpCacheManifest.add(newFile);
}

//    ... do some stuff to the cache to verify what I need.
```

Comment: What's the exception? There could be a file lock.

Comment: File.Delete can throw at least seven different exception types.  Which one are you getting?

Comment: @Roboto, Don't you mean: WTE? TCBAFL?

Comment: Is the "do some stuff to the cache" keeping hold of any files, not closing them correctly?

Comment: Jon, you removed some text too, this was wanted?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to edit the title. I didn't get a concurrency message either. Weird. Will fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I recall, Subversion marks the files in its .svn subdirectories as read-only.

Try resetting the read-only attribute before deleting the file. I don't really know any C#, but a quick Google suggests this might do the trick:

```
File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Comment: I've tested this out, and of all the suggestions so far this is the only one that actually caused an exception!

Comment: Good call! I hadn't considered "Read Only." However, it still throws the exception.

I'm really about to bash something, here. =)

Comment: GOT IT!! Finally... the second crash was due to another oddity, not this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see would be in this part:

`//    ... do some stuff to the cache to verify what I need.`

If you do open the file and forget to close it, you still have exclusive access to it, and thus can't delete it later on.

Comment: Agreed. If you're dealing with `FileStream` objects, be sure to call `Close` on them (which calls `Dispose`). Even better would be to simply wrap them in `using` blocks.

Comment: This wont be the cause - if you do that then you prevent other processes from deleting the file, however if the same process attempts to delete the file then there is no problem, as the handle / lock is owned by the same process.  I've tested this and it does not cause an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't have access to delete the file...

[system.io.file.delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)

The above link says you get `UnauthorizedAccessException` when:

> The caller does not have the required permission.
>
> -or-
>
> path is a directory.
>
> -or-
>
> path specified a read-only file.

It's one of those.

Comment: He must have access to delete the file as he had access to create the file in the first place.

Comment: Well, he said himself it's the exception that's being throw, I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions issue. Tricky one though as you obviously have write access if the File.Copy already works....

Only thing I could think of is the file still has a handle opened somewhere (as others have suggested perhaps in your *do some stuff to the cache* part).

Comment: He must have access to delete the file as he had access to create the file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: "Crash" means an exception, right? Which one? Can you catch it and show it?

Second thing: You are copying subversion repositories, although you don't care about the subversion metadata? That's what svn export is about (no .svn directory in the target).

The answer to the first question is what you really need to provide. Maybe something grabs the .svn and locks some files. TortoiseSVN maybe (to give you nice overlay icons..)?

Answer (score 0):

If a folder contains read only files, Directory.Delete won't delete it and raise the exception you're getting. For future visitors of this page, I've found a simple solution which doesn't require us to recurse through all the files and changing their read-only attribute:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"rmdir /s/q C:\Test\TestDirectoryContainingReadOnlyFiles");
```

(Change a bit to not to fire a cmd window momentarily, which is available all over the internet)

Answer (score -2):

Not understanding what you want to do so much, but what about chmoding it to 777 or 775.  :-/

Edit:

Noticed your on windows.  You'd have to change the permissions.  Don't know how windows does that :-/